# How to turn off smooth scrolling in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, mouse, macos

Since a recent update Chrome (and Slack, for that matter) has added a function that makes scrolling with a traditional mouse smooth instead of “stepped”. One would think this is a nice addition, but to me it’s jarring when all other scrolling in macOS behaves differently.

Is there a way to turn off this smooth scrolling in Chrome? I’ve tried looking in the settings, and messing with the Chrome flags (chrome://flags/), but to no avail.

Comment: No idea why you got downvoted but I would like to know the same. I can visit `chrome://flags/#smooth-scrolling` but it says "Not available for your platform".